# Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_EZCameraInfo/EZDeviceInfo/EZHCNetDeviceSDK

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Including six classes of EZOpenSDKFramWork, they cannot be undefined symbols.
I searched for relevant issues and found that they were able to add EZOpenSDKFramwork to Link Binary With Libraries in Build Phases ，but when I tried to do the same, I found that it already existed inside，then I tried to add it to Compile Sources ，but it still has no effect。

The following are all the error messages that have occurred, which belong to the EZOpenSDKFramwork.framwork Library：

> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_EZCameraInfo
>
> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_EZDevideInfo
>
> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_EZHCNetDeviceSDK
>
> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_EZOpenSDK
>
> Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_EZPlayer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.